# Zuul1 can't release the underlying httpclient's connection pool in pressure test

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-httpclient-4.x, netflix-zuul, hystrix

Zuul1's version is 1.3.1

I use jmeter to test a service through zuul and I set the number of threads is 1000, loop count is infinite. After a while, zuul's circuit breaker opend, but it never became accessable again. I found, the reason is the underlying httpclient's leased connections is full of the connection pool, but normally, they should be released after timeout. I wonder why leased connections cannot released?

My zuul1's configuration is:

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 2000
  ConnectTimeout: 1000
  MaxTotalConnections: 200
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 50

zuul:
  ribbonIsolationStrategy: THREAD

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: true
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 8000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2831

It's a bug of zuul.